# How to make an efficient Console Updater

Tags: c#

Currently i wanna display the following variable

Total Item

Total Execution

Finish Status

```
using System;

namespace ConsoleTest
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int TotalValue = 250; // Total Item Example
            int TotalExecution = 0;
            bool Finish_Status = false;
            for (int i = 0; i < TotalValue; ++i)
            {
                //Do Work Here
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(10); // Example Work
                TotalExecution++;
                if (TotalValue - TotalExecution == 0)
                {
                    Finish_Status = true;
                }
                Console.Clear();
                Console.Write("Progression Info\n             Total Item : {0}\n             Execution Total : {1}\n             Remaining : {2}\n             Finish_Status : {3}", TotalValue,TotalExecution, TotalValue - TotalExecution, Finish_Status); // Display Information To Console
            }
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

The result is good,however i was wondering if theres a much more efficient way of doing this,preferably updating it without using Console.Clear();

Comment: NO, there is not unless you clear the console it will display all ongoing message to o/p stream

Comment: If you're trying to make some sort of console progress bar you might want to look at how others have done it: https://github.com/Mpdreamz/shellprogressbar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`Console.SetCursorPosition`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.console.setcursorposition?view=netframework-4.7.2) to move the cursor around the console buffer for each write, rather than clearing the console each time.

For example:

```
using System;

namespace ConsoleTest
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int TotalValue = 250; // Total Item Example
            int TotalExecution = 0;
            bool Finish_Status = false;
            Console.Write("Progression Info\n             Total Item : \n             Execution Total : \n             Remaining : \n             Finish_Status : ");
            for (int i = 0; i < TotalValue; ++i)
            {
                //Do Work Here
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(10); // Example Work
                TotalExecution++;
                if (TotalValue - TotalExecution == 0)
                {
                    Finish_Status = true;
                }
                Console.SetCursorPosition(26, 1);
                Console.Write(TotalValue);
                Console.SetCursorPosition(31, 2);
                Console.Write(TotalExecution);
                Console.SetCursorPosition(25, 3);
                Console.Write(TotalValue - TotalExecution);
                Console.SetCursorPosition(29, 4);
                Console.Write(Finish_Status);
            }
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

*Disclaimer: Obviously the above is quick 'n' dirty, and would benefit from substantial refinement, but you get the idea.*

Answer (score 0):

Welcome kepanin_lee

I think you are looking for something like this.

```
//Console.Clear()
Console.Write(vbCr & "Progression Info\n...
```

Just start with `vbCr`, by this way you force to start on the beginning of the same line, so you only overwrite the last line, without clear all the screen.